# How to get neighbor character from highlighted text in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This returns highlighted text:

```js
function getSelection(elem) {
    var selectedText;

    if (document.selection != undefined) { // IE
        elem.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    } else if (elem.selectionStart != undefined) { // Firefox
        var startPos = elem.selectionStart;
        var endPos   = elem.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = elem.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    return selectedText;
}

$(document).on('mousedown', 'button', function(e) {
  var selection =  getSelection( $('#txtarea').get(0) );
  alert(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea">this is a test</textarea>
<button>highlighted text</button>
```

Now I need to select adjacent character from selected/highlighted text. for example if `his is a t` is selected, then I need to get both `t`(L) and `e` (R) characters. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```js
function GetSelection() {
  var selection = "";

  var textarea = document.getElementById("myArea");
  if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {
    // check whether some text is selected in the textarea
    if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) {
      selection = textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart - 1, textarea.selectionEnd + 1);
    }
  } else { // Internet Explorer before version 9
    // create a range from the current selection
    var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
    // check whether the selection is within the textarea
    var rangeParent = textRange.parentElement();
    if (rangeParent === textarea) {
      selection = textRange.text;

    }
  }

  if (selection == "") {
    alert("No text is selected.");
  } else {
    alert("The current selection is: " + selection);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="myArea" spellcheck="false">Select some text within this field.</textarea>
  <button onclick="GetSelection ()">Get the current selection</button>
</body>
```

Comment: If think it is the best choice, mark it as answer, so someone else with same req will also found helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the textarea using

```
var preview=document.getElementById("txtarea");
```

Get it's content using

```
var str=preview.value
```

The string to be matched

```
x="his is a t"
```

Using indexOf to get the character at which it starts

```
res=str.indexOf(x)
```

**this returns 1**

To find the character before it(check for res!=0)

```
str.charAt(res-1)
```

**Returns "t"**

For the last char

```
str.charAt(res+x.length)
```

**Returns "e"**